# Converting Finalbuilder 6 project to Fb 5

Tags: finalbuilder

I have a Fb 6 project, and i need it to be converted to FB 5.

Are there any tools to let me achieve this?
Note: The FB 6 project i have does not use any FB 6 version specific features.

Answer (score 0):

We have just started upgrading from 5 to 6, and I can't see that it has changed much.

If its uncompressed, I would try just renaming the fb6 project from fbp6 to fbp5 and then open it.

A compressed finalbuilder project is just a zipfile with the uncompressed file inside, so I guess you could do the same with compressed projects. If not, you could just uncompress it your self and then rename the uncompressed script.